# Repository.Checkout() doesn't unstage submodule changes

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

If I have a repo in this status

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   App_Data/Submodule
        modified:   file.txt
```

with `App_Data/Submodule` being a git submodule and `file.txt` is just a normal file.

Running `git checkout master --force` will put the repo in this condition

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   App_Data/Submodule (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

but doing the same from LibGit2Sharp using the following code

```
using (var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(RepositoryPath))
{
  repo.Checkout("master", new CheckoutOptions { CheckoutModifiers = CheckoutModifiers.Force });
}
```

leaves the repo in this state

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   App_Data/Submodule
```

Calling reset however works as expected.

```
using (var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(RepositoryPath))
{
    repo.Reset(ResetMode.Hard, "master");
}
```

Is that behavior expected from LibGit2Sharp? Should I be calling Reset myself if I want to mirror exactly the same git behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was asked a year ago, but I figure I'll provide a solution I found. Maybe the implementation has changed since in LibGit2Sharp.

`Repository.Checkout` with the `CheckoutModifiers.Force` was not working for me to unstage my submodule change, but `Repository.Unstage` on the relative path to the submodule did.